# aptana studio: debug rspec

Tags: ruby, aptana

I would like to debug with the integrated aptana studio debugger a rspec file.

The problem is: how do I tell aptana the invocation command is:

```
bundle exec rspec [my_spec_file]
```

and not simply

```
ruby
```

Of course I need the longer invocation cmd to load all prerequisites.